# What's the best way to run guard in emacs

Tags: ruby, emacs, guard

Currently, in order to run guard (a deamon which runs my application's tests automatically), I open shell mode and run the command there, also renaming the buffer to *guard*.

Though, I'd like that the pathes printed along the test would be clickable in the buffer, and I'd like the buffer to auto-scroll, even if not visible.

What can I do in order to get this behaviour?

Comment: `M-x compilation-minor-mode` should at least get you clickable paths.

Comment: so `(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'compilation-shell-minor-mode)` in your init file to always get clickable paths in shell mode: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Shell#Make_file_paths_clickable

Answer (score 1):

looking for documentation with `C-h d RET comint scroll RET`, we see that the variable `comint-output-filter-functions` is a variable containing a list of functions to run after the output is inserted. One of them is `comint-postoutput-scroll-to-bottom`. Mine is set accordingly and I have the expected behaviour (in shell-mode, not in compilation mode though).

Comment: I have also discovered that it is posible to run guard with the option --clear or to use the .guardrc file to allways have this behaviour.